# Search / retrieve single value from one to many relationships Core Data Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nsarray, nspredicate, nsset

My data design allows one user to have many votes; and each single record can also have many votes. I'm struggling massively with referencing and searching for a specific element relying on these

[image]

In the master view controller, I've a fetch controller on the Record entity, and a single var user entity (ie. the device-user) that is inserted into the same managedContext.

Assuming this is OK, when preparing for segue to detailed view controller, I want to pass in the selected record (no problem); an array of all votes for that record (I think no problem, code below); and (here's the tricky part) the optional device-user's vote for that record (this is my question).

```
let votesAsSet = record.votes
controller.votes = votesAsSet?.allObjects as? [Vote]

let predicateForUsersVote = NSPredicate(format: "record.votes.user == user")
let thisUsersVoteForThisRecordAsSet = votesAsSet?.filteredSetUsingPredicate(predicateForUsersVote)                

controller.thisUsersVote = thisUsersVoteForThisRecordAsSet!.first as? Vote
```

What I'm trying to do is to iterate through the user's votes in core data for one where the record's user matches the device-user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your predicate is already operating on the set of `Votes` for the `record`, you can just use the `user` property directly.  But you must substitute in the correct value for the device-user, eg:

```
let predicateForUsersVote = NSPredicate(format: "user == %@", device-user)
```

The result of applying this predicate to the set will also be a set, so I think you may need to use `.anyObject()` rather than `.first` to get the relevant `Vote` object.

Comment: My God it works!!! I've read a lot about predicates, NSSets and Core Data, and your answer brings it together nicely. One supplementary question if you've a moment: why not just "user == user" or "user == self.user", both of which seem to work?

Comment: Within a predicate, `user` refers to the `user` property **of the object being evaluated**: in this case, each `Vote` object from the set.  Likewise `self` refers to the object itself.  So both "user == user" and "user == self.user" compare the `user` property of the object with the `user` property of the object, and will both evaluate to true for all objects - not just the device-user.

Comment: If you want to compare with a value from the code where you build the predicate, you have to substitute the value in using the %@ format.